# Changing value of select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to change the value a select box when a certain option is chosen. I have searched for ways to do this but nothing that I have found works.

This is what I have:

```
(function () {
    var pdc

    $("#dclist").focus(function(){
        pdc = this.value;
    }).change(function () {
        var ndc = this.value;
        if (ndc === "Select") {
                $("#dclist").val(pdc);
            } else {
                //something else
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

Here is the select box:

```
<select id="dclist">
   <option value="Select">Please select</option>
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Ryan

Comment: if you post your HTML that will be helpful

Comment: I think you need to get the option element and give it a `checked="checked"` attribute instead of setting the value attribute of the `select` element.

Comment: @JosephMarikle -- Setting the `select` `value` attribute will work

Comment: @tymeJV oops! yeah.  `select` or `selected`.  Something like that :P

Comment: `<option value="1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>` is the correct way to select

Comment: You have an extra } after your else clause by the way. Using the browser console will show you that.

Comment: Your code works fine after removing the extra `}`, though you have to select an option other than the default, then un- and re-focus. A small change here makes it work better I think: http://jsfiddle.net/E2N8H/. Also, make sure you are using a DOM ready handler so the dropdown exists when you bind the handler to it.

Comment: Here's a suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/NN9NU/

Answer (score 1):

-snip-

Edit: Jason P has the correct answer.  It was just a syntax error.  If Jason P posts an answer I'll delete this one.

Comment: @JasonP well that changes everything... post an answer.  The problem must have been just the syntax error

Comment: If value select is selected I want the previous selection to go back rather than just going back to option one. That's why I set pdc to the previous value on focus.

Comment: @rbradshaw See the comment I posted. After removing the extra `}`, your code works.

Comment: @rbradshaw I think there are better ways to do that but it should probably be in a different question.  Your issue here is just the syntax error